# Why won't this code display Error: Could not find file when e is thrown by a nonexistant file?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Here is my code. The FileNotFoundException is not being thrown for some reason when i give it a fileName that does not exist.

```
 public static String Question1( String fileName )
 {   
    String message = ""; 
    if ( fileName == null )
    {   
        fileName = "files/question1/sample.txt"; 
    }

    try
    {  

        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner( new File ( fileName ));

        while ( fileScan.hasNext() )
        {
            String readLine = fileScan.nextLine();

            if ( message.equals( "" ) )
            {
                message = readLine + "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                message = message + readLine + "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        message = "Error: Could not find file!";
    }

    return message;
 }
```

When i run the code with a fileName that does not exist, the message returned is "" instead of "Error: Could not find file!"

Comment: Have you debugged the code and are you sure the exception is caught?

Comment: *Clearly* the file *does* exist. ***Obviously.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call shenanigans :-) I suspect the file *does* exist in your case since this code works just fine:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    public static String Question1(String fileName) {   
        String message = "";
        if ( fileName == null )
            fileName = "files/question1/sample.txt"; 

        try {  
            Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
                String readLine = fileScan.nextLine();
                if (message.equals("")) {
                    message = readLine + "\n";
                } else {
                    message = message + readLine + "\n";
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            message = "Error: Could not find file!";
        }

        return message;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Question1("no_such_file.txt"));
    }
}
```

Running that outputs, as expected:

```
Error: Could not find file!
```

When I *create* that file, the program outputs its contents.

I suggest going back to look at your file system again, then run your code through a single-stepping debugger to track the code flow.

Comment: You're right. I changed the file name in the unit test from blah.txt to blahlsdfjs.txt and now its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the exception `FileNotFoundException` is thrown?

What could be happening is at the relative path of where this class is placed ,the file that you think is not present,could be present.